# SVN changes between 2 tags in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am using Jenkins to create a release package. Once job complete I am tagging new build with specific version in SVN. Now,  at this moment I need to generate an email to project's lead developer with a report, which will show changes between 2 SVN tags, so Lead Dev can have a quick look on what is going to production. Anybody had experience like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this in mercurial.  I took the hg log between 2 tags and saved that to a file.  So something like svn log -r[tag] i think that will get from the tag to the tip.  http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=613

Comment: Using a range is also a generic option, e.g. : svn [svn url or local checkout dir] log -r (from tag rev#):(to tag rev#). That works well if you use a trunk for the usvn url, and you do not have commits on your tags.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the tags then write a shell build step that executes (depending on the structure of your repo) something like `svn diff http://<repo>/tags/<tag1> http://<repo>/tags/<tag2> > diff.txt` (you can add `--summarize` as well). Now, `diff.txt` will 'live' in your workspace. You then can use [EmailExt plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) to include *diff.txt* contents in the e-mail with `${FILE}` token (EmailExt plugin token reference will be provided via '?' icon when you check 'Editable e-mail notification' box).

Make sure to delete `diff.txt` before running next build ([Workspace Cleanup plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin) may help).

Comment: svn diff can be heavy, it shows line level changes, unlike svn log. Still valid of course if that's what you're looking for, but IMHO svn log is normally enough if the commit messages are descriptive and reference e.g. JIRA tickets.